# MySQL Composite primary key uniqueness

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to make composite primary key in mySQL. In table1 i need to set id1,id2 as composite primary key. i used this query. But it makes each as primary key. it checks duplicates of each entry

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
   ADD PRIMARY KEY(
     `id1`,
     `id2`);
```

When i insert two rows

```
insert "a","b" 
insert "a","c"
```

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '1408181771009' for key 'pk_sentiments'

But

```
insert "a","c" 
insert "b","c"
```

works fine. I could not understand this behavior. How to resolve this?

Comment: you are assuming ("a", "b") is being inserted as (id1, id2), but that's not the case because the error reports different values. What is your table structure?

Comment: it is just two strings. in my case id1-id2 need to be primary key but when i insert same id1 but different id2 it shows this error

Comment: Your `alter` statement creates a composit key.

Comment: what is this 'pk_sentiments' i don't have any foreign key relation in that name.

Comment: Why unique key not good for you?

Comment: i want this as a composite primary key. But it throws errors even 1 key matches

Comment: your primary key delcaration is fine, the problem must be in your table. show the ddl statement. Also, does it have data in it already?

Comment: `pk_sentiments` can **not** be the primary you created. The primary key constraint in MySQL is *always* called `PRIMARY` - there is no way you can give it a different name

Comment: i could not what is this pk_sentiment i searched every where in my table i don't have any constraints named pk_sentiments

Comment: if you are using mysql workbench, choose "alter table" and look into the indexes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD UNIQUE KEY `id1_id2` (`id1`, `id2`);
```